# In Rails: should I use 2 join tables for different meanings or just 1 with a `meaning` column?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, join

In my **Rails** app, I have those two models, `A` and `B`. They have two many-to-many relationships, meaning different things. Should I create two join tables, one for each meaning, or a single table with a `meaning` column?

Given I'm trying to do stuff teh *Rails way*, what should I do?

Also, what if I had even more associations with different meanings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe this is a matter of doing things the *Rails way*. However...

I would go with the option of one table. You could have some sort of "meaning" column. Or, could use something like the [acts_as_taggable_on](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on) gem and have the tag confer the meaning.

Comment: I did go for that!

Comment: Awesome! I hope it goes well. Good luck!